# Read a sql file ,store ina variable,ignorecomments from file and execute in DB through Python

Tags: python

Hi I Have to read a sql file from python code..store it in a variable and execute it database.But while storing it in a variable it taking comment also .I have to ignore lines with comment

Code i tried:`enter code here`

```
with open ("/home/dbadmin/EB_Python/test.sql","r") as myfile:
  query=myfile.read().replace('\n',' ')
loadnm="test_load_01"
if vlj.load(loadnm,'target table', 'source table_dimension', query):
    print vlj.query_rslt()..
```

my sample sql file is something like..

```
------INserting into a table
insert into target_table
select col1
---Just check comment
from source_table where  col1<>1;
```

but while reading it its taking it as :

```
------INserting into a table insert into target_table select col1
---Just check comment from source_table where  col1<>1;
```

So not allowing me to execute this query..How can i skip or ignore comment part

Comment: with open ("/home/dbadmin/EB_Python/test.sql","r") as myfile:
 statement = " ".join(line.strip() for line in myfile if not line startswith("--"))
        query=myfile.read().replace('\n',' ')
  print query

Comment: Its showing syntax error : at startswith:

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to strip the comments from each line individually before removing the newlines. As long as the comment markers are always at the start of the line (rather than following some SQL) you could try this:

```
with open ("/home/dbadmin/EB_Python/test.sql","r") as myfile:
    query = " ".join(line.strip() for line in myfile if not line.startswith("--"))
```

Comment: showing syntax error at startswith:    I tried this:
with open ("/home/dbadmin/EB_Python/test.sql","r") as myfile:
 statement = " ".join(line.strip() for line in myfile if not line startswith("--"))
        query=myfile.read().replace('\n',' ')
  print query

Comment: with open ("/home/dbadmin/EB_Python/test.sql","r") as myfile:
    statement = " ".join(line.strip() for line in myfile if not line.startswith("--")
        query=myfile.read().replace('\n',' ')
  print query

Comment: with open ("/home/dbadmin/EB_Python/test.sql","r") as myfile:
    statement = " ".join(line.strip() for line in myfile if not line.startswith("--")
        query=myfile.read().replace('\n',' ')
  print query
Its still gigving error at query line no 3: can u check whether m doing hte right thing

Comment: I've edited the code. But you are supposed to understand it, not just copy it blindly